# Как удалить определенное значение из текстового файла? Python

Tags: python, файлы, txt

Имеется ids.txt файл с id пользователей в каждой строке:

```
1234
1256
5125
6246
```

Нужен код, который удаляет запрашиваемый id, если такой имеется в документе.

```
del = input('id')

ids = open('ids.txt', '*режим*' , encoding='UTF-8')
if del in ids:
    #код для удаления id в переменной del из файла ids
```

Если есть чудо-способ без удаления и создания нового файла, то буду очень рад

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно просто перезаписать текущий файл. Открыть его сначала на чтение, поместить строки в переменную, потом на запись и записывать в него то, что вам нужно

```
with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("yourfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip("\n") != "ненужный id":
            f.write(line)
```

Или вот такой способ с одним опеном, подсмотрел его на англоязычном SO, но не проверял. Открываем файл в режиме "r+":

```
with open("yourfile.txt", "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0) # устанавливаем указатель в начало файла, перед имеющимися значениями
    for line in lines:
        if line != "ненужный id":
            f.write(line)
    f.truncate() # усекаем файл до позиции, на которой стоит указатель в данный момент
```

И не называйте переменные именами имеющихся дефолтных функций/методов (del)

Comment: Про переменные знаю, я по памяти написал, пока доступа к пк не было. Сейчас все проверил, оба варианта рабочие (во втором так же надо указать `if line.strip("\n")`. Спасибо огромное!